# Microsoft Word power shell script to skip all deleted revision line/paragraph

Tags: powershell

I m trying to read a word document and fetching number from the particular paragraph or sentence. But some of the sentence are deleted and the revision track is on. So my output still consist of deleted sentence with expected number. Basically i dont want to include in output with deleted sentence. Also i cant save the file with accept all revision.

My code is as given below.

```
$file2 = "C:\work\Powershell\Scenarios\ALPtest Life AnnualV12.docx"

$word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$document = $word.documents.open($file2,$false,$true)


if ($document.Content.Find.Execute('Document Conditions'))
{
    Write-Host $WantFile "contains 'Document Conditions'" `n
    $Paras = $Document.Paragraphs 
                  
    foreach($para in $paras)
    {
        $Text= $para.Range.Text

        if ($text.Trim() -eq 'Document Conditions')
        {
            Write-Host "Hurahhhhhhh"
            $start=1

        }
        elseif ( $start -eq 1 -and ($text -match "[0-9]"))
        {
            if ($text.Revsision -ne "wdRevisionDelete")
            {
                Write-Host "Found revision del : $text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Highly appreciated for your help to sort this .

Comment: Shouldn't you use the [WdRevisionType Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdrevisiontype) value `2` rather than the string `"wdRevisionDelete"` ?

Comment: that is not working.$text.Revsision never gets 2

Comment: So then, what **does** `$text.Revision` reveal?? BTW, you have a typo there `$text.Revsision` should be `$text.Revision`